# What does "In past terms" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am learning this MIT [course](https://youtu.be/XNhOk80CeWo?t=647).

The professor said:

> **In past terms** we compared a human genome to a rat genome, and
>   discovered they were pretty similar.

What does "In past terms" mean?

I listened to this point many times, and this does not sound like "In past times".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, [*term*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/term) means:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **3** : division in a school year during which instruction is regularly given to students

So, to paraphrase the sentence:

> In **earlier classes** we compared a human genome to a rat genome, and discovered they were pretty similar.